# uninitialized constant ::ActiveResource

Tags: ruby, activeresource, initialization

I try to call an API. I just want use active resource so I make this code in a simple file .rb:

```
class Order < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "http://localhost:3000/api/"
    self.element_name = "order"
    self.format = ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat
end
```

When I call this file who should do the init he throw me an error:

```
$ ruby test/test_order.rb 
test/test_order.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant ActiveRessource (NameError)
```

I try to create a new rvm gemset and just install activeresource

```
rvm gemset create delete_me
rvm use 1.9.3@delete_me
gem install activeresource
```

He throw me the same error. I try with ruby 1.9.2 same error.

The activeresource's version I've try is 3.1.3 and 3.2.6

Thanks.

Comment: In the error ActiveRessource is declared with two SS why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to require ActiveResource. You can do that like so:

```
require 'active_resource'
```

You will also probably need to require rubygems before your require activeresource:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_resource'
```

Comment: I add this:require 'rubygems'
gem 'activeresource'
require 'active_resource' and it's work thanks.